# Pydrive: How to upload a large file or in chunks?

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, pydrive

I'm trying to upload a large csv compressed file (~6GB) to Google Drive via PyDrive, but everytime I try to do the upload via:

```
file = self.drive.CreateFile({
  'title': file_name,
  'parents': [{ 'id': parent_id }],
  'mimeType': mime_type,
})
file.SetContentFile(file_path)
file.Upload()
```

I get the following error:
`httplib2.RedirectMissingLocation: Redirected but the response is missing a Location: header.`.

I'm using Python 3.7.

Anyone knows if I can upload large files or upload chunk by chunk via Pydrive?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Try using pydrive2 library instead. https://github.com/iterative/PyDrive2. It does not have the issue with the file size.